# How can I find substitutions which give me sparse representations for algebraic manifolds?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polynomials, soft-question, algorithms

I am curious how I can find substitutions which will allow me to more efficiently store level sets of multivariable real coefficient polynomials.

Example:
$$(x+y-1)^2 + 4(y-x+3)^2 - 4^2 = 0$$

which expands into $5x^2 - 6xy -26x +5y^2 +22y + 21 = 0$

we can see by ocular inspection that if we do a simple linear change of variables $$\cases{(x+y-1)\to x\\2(y-x+3) \to y}$$

We will get

$$x^2 + y^2 - 4^2 = 0$$

From six to three coefficients.

Useful both in understanding as well as data compression as we now see that it "in some sense" is a circle.

So to my question. If I have a general non-sparse multivariate polynomial.

Which methods exist to find a transformation to yield the sparse representation?